# Opsgenie - Create Alert API doesn't set responders tag

Tags: opsgenie

I'm having issues with the Opsgenie's API integration and creating alerts.

In their docs, they state that you can set the **responders** field to a user or team, but upon creating the alert I can't see this field set properly.

E.g.
When sending a create alert/POST request to their alerts endpoint https://api.eu.opsgenie.com/v2/alerts, with this payload

```
{
    "message": "Alert Sample",
    "responders": [
        {
            "type": "user",
            "name": "some-user"
        }
    ],
    "priority": "P5"
}
```

an alert will be created indeed, but the given **responders** field will be set to the user/team who owns the API integration (the team for which the API integration was created for). Meaning, the **responders** field will always be set to the same value as the **owner** field, e.g.
**owner**=team-name, **responders**=team-name.

What am I missing? Is there any way you an set the responders field to a value different from the owner?

Is this a bug in their API integration or do I just have have a wrong expectation what these fields represent?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether the order of "name" and "type" is relevant here, but in following sample they first set "name" and then "type": https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Opsgenie-questions/Re-Re-Cannot-use-Responder-or-Tags-in-API-to-Create-an/qaq-p/1312154/comment-id/412#M412

Another consideration: as you already said, in a team-level API integration the responder is automatically the team who owns the integration. Maybe this is not supposed to be overridden.
Did you also try to set the responder in a global API integration? (those are available only in Standard or Enterprise plan and have to be implemented by the OpsGenie-Owner)